# How to access data in RecyclerView from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I know, this question asked many times but I am totally lost after reading some answers. I am new to Android development. I have created a Fragment and initialized and set the adapter from that fragment

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ConfigDataloggerViewModel.class);
 dataLoggerList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DataLoggerStringArray);
 // TODO: Use the ViewModel
 //for (int j=0; j< dataLoggerList.length; j++){ DummyArrayList.add(dataLoggerList[j]);}
 RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.config_datalogger_recycle_view);

 ConfigDataloggerAdapter configDataloggerAdapter = new ConfigDataloggerAdapter(dataLoggerList, getActivity());
 recyclerView.setAdapter(configDataloggerAdapter);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

I have list of EditText in my fragment and I am setting those EditText in the adapter and I am also saving the values from EditTexts into an Array which is defined in Adapter itself.

```
public class ConfigDataloggerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConfigDataloggerAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    //private ArrayList<RFIDReader> readers = new ArrayList<>();
    private String [] mDummyList ;
   // private ArrayList<String> mDummyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public String [] mDummyArrayList;
    //public ArrayList<String> mConfigDataloggerData ;
    public  String[] mConfigDataloggerData;
   // private ConfigDataloggerViewModel mConfigDataModel;
    public Map<String, String> tempDataModel = new HashMap<>();

    private Context mContext;


    public ConfigDataloggerAdapter( String [] mDummyArrayList, Context mContext) {
        this.mDummyArrayList = mDummyArrayList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mConfigDataloggerData = new String[mDummyArrayList.length];


    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.config_datalogger_list,viewGroup,false);

        ConfigDataloggerAdapter.ViewHolder holder = new  ConfigDataloggerAdapter.ViewHolder(view);


        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  ConfigDataloggerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        String [] mConfigDataloggerText = null;
       // for (int j=0; j< mDummyList.length; j++){ mDummyArrayList.add(mDummyList[j]);}
        //ReaderDevice readerDevice = mDummyArrayList.get(i);
        String temp = mDummyArrayList[i];
        holder.mConfigDataloggerListText.setText(temp);
       // tempDataModel.put(temp,mConfigDataloggerData.get(i) );
      // mConfigDataModel.setConfigDataloggerVMData(tempDataModel);




        //holder.reader_checkedTextView.setText(readerDevice.getName()  );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDummyArrayList.length;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public TextView mConfigDataloggerListText;
        public EditText mConfigDataloggarListEditText;
        public LinearLayout configDataloggerLayout;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mConfigDataloggerListText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_config_datalogger);
            mConfigDataloggarListEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText_config_datalogger);

            mConfigDataloggarListEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    mConfigDataloggerData[getAdapterPosition()] = 
                                     mConfigDataloggarListEditText.getText().toString();
                //here I am storing data from editText to the array

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            configDataloggerLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.config_datalogger_list_layout);

        }
    }


}
```

I have two questions, 1) how to access `mConfigDataloggerData` from adapter in the Fragment? 2) I have a button in same fragment. when I press the button, other fragment starts. Now, I want to save data from `mConfigDataloggerData` to ViewModel when press the button. So where exactly I write `mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(xxxx.class);` ?

For your reference, below code is of an activity where my Fragments are attached.

```
public class defaultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "default activity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.datalogger_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ConfigDataloggerFragment configDataloggerFragment = new ConfigDataloggerFragment();

       // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.default_datalogger_activity, datalogger).commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.default_datalogger_activity, configDataloggerFragment).commit();

    }


    public void StartorStopInventory(View view) {

        Button button = (Button) view;
        if (application.mConnectedReader.isConnected()){
            if (application.mIsInventoryRunning ){
                application.mIsInventoryRunning = true;
                button.setText("STOP");
                try{
                    TriggerInfo triggerInfo = new TriggerInfo();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Start trigger setting when button is pressed" + triggerInfo.StartTrigger.getTriggerType());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Stop trigger setting when button is pressed" + triggerInfo.StartTrigger.getTriggerType());
                    application.mConnectedReader.Actions.Inventory.perform();
                }catch (InvalidUsageException e){
                    Log.d(TAG, "StartorStopInventory: Inventory perform fail " + e);
                } catch (final OperationFailureException op) {
                    op.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "StartorStopInventory: Operational failure " + op.getResults() + " " + op.getVendorMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), op.getVendorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void start_data_logging_click(View view) {
        Datalogger datalogger = new Datalogger();
       // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.default_datalogger_activity, datalogger);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.default_datalogger_activity, datalogger);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Create getters in Adapter for your fields, ex

```
public String[] getConfigDataloggerData(){
    return mConfigDataloggerData;
}
...
```

To declare adapter globally;

```
   public class YourFragment {
      ConfigDataloggerAdapter configDataloggerAdapter,

   public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ConfigDataloggerViewModel.class);
     dataLoggerList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DataLoggerStringArray);
     // TODO: Use the ViewModel
     //for (int j=0; j< dataLoggerList.length; j++){ DummyArrayList.add(dataLoggerList[j]);}
     RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.config_datalogger_recycle_view);

      configDataloggerAdapter = new ConfigDataloggerAdapter(dataLoggerList, getActivity());
     recyclerView.setAdapter(configDataloggerAdapter);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

     }
    }
```

Then inside your Fragment, call `configDataloggerAdapter.getConfigDataloggerData()` and you will get your data. Same for other fields

**2)** I dont yet understand that part

Comment: Thanks, in fragment, in which method should I call getter method? I am creating an object of an adapter in OnActivityCreate method in the fragment.

Comment: Doesnt matter, In which method do you want to access that data you can call it there, but if you want to call it other than  OnActivityCreate, you wont be able to access Adapter object. So declare your Adapter as Global variable, so you can access it everywhere in Fragment

Comment: See answer for making it global

Comment: Thanks, I called getter method in onPause of fragment. it's working perfectly. I still need to find out answer to the second question about viewModel. I will make another post.